# Macro definition in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am a new programmer in C/C++ having programmed in Java for quite a while. I am currently understanding some C code. Here I am seeing some macro definitions like:

```
/* Flags for ds_flags */ 
#define DSF_OVER        (1<<0)  
#define DSF_DISPLAY     (1<<1)    
#define DSF_CALLFLOW    (1<<2)
```

I am not able to understand why do we have to define these macros in such a manner. What is the advantage gained in these rather than in defining like:

```
#define DSF_OVER        0
#define DSF_DISPLAY     1    
#define DSF_CALLFLOW    2
```

Comment: Ideally the this code should have used bit-shift `template` instead of this hand coded `<<` shift operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times the position of the bits represent some bit operations like in your case:

```
#define DSF_OVER        (1<<0)  is 1
#define DSF_DISPLAY     (1<<1)  is 2  
#define DSF_CALLFLOW    (1<<2)  is 4 (This is not 3)
```

If you were to add a new item later, you will do it as

```
#define DSF_OVER       1
#define DSF_DISPLAY    2  
#define DSF_CALLFLOW   4
#define DSF_CALLNEW    5.
```

You cant have a value 5 here since it is two bits enabled (101 in binary). To avoid such potential errors it is always safe to use macros using `>>`. It can't produce a value of 5 (101) by error in when the next bit should be 1000 in binary.

It is all about programming convenience to produce error free code.

Comment: if you're going to add random stuff after a define, it should probably be commented.  Even if this isn't really code. (Also, you made `DSF_CALLNEW` a literal `double`.)

Answer (score 7):

When seeing something like

```
#define DSF_FOO 0x800
#define DSF_BAR 2048
```

not many people are able to quickly see that only one bit is set, and which it is.

```
#define DSF_FOO (1<<11)
```

however makes this very clear.

Comment: The problem is likely the macro name. Had it been DSF_MASK, you would immediately realize what 0x800 meant.

Comment: @Lundin: I doubt that the macro name makes any difference in recognizing the bit that is set. Regardless of the name, not many people will see what bits are set in 134217728.

Comment: It doesn't mean that a bit it set, it is a mask. You can use it either as REG |= DSF_MASK or REG &= ~DSF_MASK. If you think the (1<<11) style means that a bit is set, rather than "this is a bit mask", that only means that the style is for worse.

Comment: @Lundin: You *can* use it as a mask. But you don't have to. `(1<<11)` is simply a very convenient syntax to see "oh, bit 11 is set". That such things are often used as bitmasks is a different thing, but it doesn't mean this has to be used as a bitmask for setting flags, it can be used as a building block for other things too.

Answer (score 5):

The only potential advantage is that it's easier to see that the code correctly defines each constant with one distinct bit set.

Most people will see that at a glance anyway if you just write 1, 2, 4 instead of `1<<0`, `1<<1`, `1<<2`, so perhaps it's difficult to see that advantage in this example. Once you get to `1<<15`, some people would miss a typo like 32748.

Answer (score 2):

These are bit values, e.g. 1, 2, 4. 8.

```
Bit 0 = (1 << 0) = 1
Bit 1 = (1 << 1) = 2
Bit 2 = (1 << 2) = 4
Bit 3 = (1 << 3) = 8
...etc...
```

It's a more convenient and robust way of defining them than using explicit values, especially as the bit indices get larger (e.g. `(1<<15)` is much easier to understand and more intuitive than `32768` or `0x8000`, in that it obviously means "bit 15" rather than some possibly arbitrary number).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. But can you please explain a bit elaborately. What would have been the difference if we had defined these as --

Comment: #define DSF_OVER 1 #define DSF_DISPLAY 2
#define DSF_CALLFLOW 4

Comment: I think all can agree that 32768 isn't intuitive, but I don't agree that (1 << 15) is more intuitive than 0x8000. Hex _should_ be intuitive to every programmer. But how to write this is really a matter of subjective personal taste, I'd be careful with labelling one style better than another.

Comment: @Lundin: as well as readability and intuitiveness there are also the issues of robustness, flexibility and ease of maintenance - it's much easier to change a field such as `(1<<15)` to say `(1<<16)`, and of course it's much better to use symbolic names for bit positions, so `(1<<TX_READY_BIT)` is always going to be better than `0x8000`.

Comment: Readability and ease of maintenance is the same thing. I don't quite see how it is harder or easier to change 15 to 16, compared with 0x8000 to 0x10000. All programmers know hex. However, something very interesting happens in this example! With the hex notation I naturally realize I have overstepped a 16-bit boundary, because suddenly I have to write an extra digit. Suppose the variable I was working with was 16 bit. If so, the bug was spotted at the point it was written. With shift notation, you don't see this. Robustness anyone? I also hope you mean TX_READY_BIT, rather than 1<<TX_READY_BIT.

Comment: No, readability and ease of maintenance are *not* the same thing, although the form certainly contributes towards the latter. And no, I meant `(1<<TX_READY_BIT)` - the point being that you can define bit *numbers*, e.g. with an enum or whatever, and then define the *masks* which correspond to these bit numbers, e.g. `const uint32_t TX_READY_MASK = 1 << TX_READY_BIT;`.

Comment: @Lundin: just to be clear, are you really saying that it's easier to see that `0x10000` requires more than 16 bits, than to see that `1<<16` requires more than 16 bits? I don't find it easier, since in the former case I have to count the zeros, multiply by 4 (bits per nibble), then add 1. In the latter case I just have to add 1 (to 16). I wouldn't say that `0x8000` is particularly difficult to read, or to figure out that it has bit 15 set, but to me it's even easier to see that `1<<15` has bit 15 set. The clue is the "15".

Comment: That said, `1<<16` invokes UB when `int` is 16 bits wide, whereas in that case `0x10000` is a `long`, and hence behavior when you use it is defined albeit potentially surprising. That's nothing to do with readability, but is to do with the robustness you mentioned.

Comment: @Steve: Yes 0x10000 is easier to see, you will get a "wait a minute..." moment as soon as you go outside 16 bits. When changing from 15 to 16 you will just change the number without thinking, especially since it says *16*. 1<<16 should be fine for a 16-bit integer, right? It will be easy to write that bug.

Comment: @Paul: In this context it is, because while you can write a program that is easy to read but hard to maintain, you cannot write a program that is easy to maintain but hard to read.

Comment: "All programmers know hex." This is utter nonsense. Most programmers don't know hex by heart. We live in 2011 where the main problems lie in abstractions and good design and high level language features. Only a minority of programmers still have to fiddle with bits, and even less want to do so. And even for those that do fiddle with bits, in the times of 64bit systems things like 0x200000000 are nowhere near readable nor a "wait a minute, I overstepped the 32bit border" moment. Additionally no one really wants to bother with "I need bit 61 set, what is the hex for it?"

Answer (score 2):

Using `(1<<x)` in a define makes it clear that the value is a single bit and not a number.

For the compiler it makes no difference because `(1<<2)` is computed at compile time and not at runtime. Showing clearly that they are single-bit values is instead useful for whoever reads the code because for example they could be multiple values that can be combined or that a single variable can be used to store multiple flags:

```
// Multiple options are combined with bitwise-or
show_message(DSF_CAPTION|DSF_ALERT, "Hey...");
...

// Checking is made using bitwise-and, not equality
if (status & DSF_RUNNING)
  ...
```

Also requiring specific bits is sometimes needed when dealing with hardware (e.g. on a certain I/O port may be you need to specify the fifth bit because that's how the hardware is wired, and `(1<<4)` is more readable than `16` for that).

Comment: Hello all...thanks for the explanations it is beginning to make sense to now. Since (1 << x) uses only one bit I think one obvious advantage gained here is efficient memory usage since we are not using 8 or more bits. Correct ?

Comment: @user496934: sometimes it's about saving space, but quite often is just more useful to store multiple independent logical values in a single integer field. The advantage to using an explicit `std::set` is that you get "set literals" and a more compact syntax (that it's still quite readable to trained eyes). Also requiring specific bits is sometimes needed when dealing with hardware (e.g. on a certain I/O port may be you need to specify the fifth bit because that's how the hardware is wired, and `(1<<4)` is more readable than `16` for that).

Answer (score 1):

It's for clarity really - it shows that the different definitions are bit masks that will typically be used together to filter values from an input. I don't know if you already know what a bit mask is - here's a link: http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you prefer `(1 << n)` or not, everyone should be aware of what hexadecimal numbers signify. Whenever you encounter hex in source code it always means that som bit- or byte manipulations are taking place. You don't use hex notation for any other purpose. Therefore it is wise to write masks, numeric bit manipulation literals etc as hex.

Comment: Not worth a -1, but this simply isn't true. Sometimes magic numbers are chosen to be "interesting" in hex, such as the 0xCAFEBABE that introduces Java byte code. That's never involved in bit manipulation, but it would be absurd to write in in source code as decimal.

Comment: @Steve Yes indeed, that's the sole reason why programmers are using hexadecimal numbers: to write nerdy jokes involving the letters ABCDEF. It has nothing at all to do with hex being more convenient to read than raw binary numbers.

Comment: Do you genuinely think I'm claiming it's the "sole reason", or are you just bad at being corrected?

Comment: No, I was genuinely sarcastic :)